# How to retrieve metrics from vROps dashboard using vRealize Operations API?

Tags: cloud, vmware

I am currently working on automating performance monitoring using vRealize Operations Manager (vROps). I would like to know how I can retrieve specific metrics from a vROps dashboard using the vROps API.

[image]

I have gone through the official documentation, but I haven't found clear examples or specific methods for programmatically extracting this data. Does anyone have any advice, code examples, or useful resources to guide me in the right direction?

[image]